# Adding authentication module to an existing servlet 3 app without modifying it

Tags: servlets, module, websphere

I need to add an authentication layer to an existing Servlet 3 web application which is deployed with a *.war file **without modifying it** (because I do not own it).

I have a vague idea of how this can be achieved, however I am not sure of the details of how this can be done and if this is possible at all.

The vague idea I have is to add another web module to the application and make it intercept all requests and check if there is an active session. If there is, then I allow the request to be handled by the original web module, if not then I make user authenticate, create session and redirect user to the original url. By the way, the container I am using is IBM WebSphere so having *.ear files is ok.

I have no idea where to start from. I imagine that I can implement a servlet filter on the authentication module, but how can I make the original application also use this filter?

Comment: You are providing too little detail what you want to achieve and what are your requirements. But I'd suggest to implement it as TAI (Trust Association Interceptor) see this article [Advanced authentication in WebSphere Application Server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0508_benantar/0508_benantar.html) as a good starting point.

Comment: @Gas, thanks a lot for the suggestion. I when that way, and now trying to implement service provider initiated authentication using WebSphere's SAML TAI functionality. There are lot of things to get right before I will get this to work, but at least I know I am on the right way now.